# Using grunt-conventional-changelog retroactively

Tags: node.js, git, gruntjs, changelog

I'm using grunt-conventional-changelog in my build process, and it's fantastic. However, I can't seem to figure out how to get this grunt task to parse all of my previous commits and git tags from before I added this task to my build flow.

Is there an option I can specify to retroactively go through my git history and generate a changelog? I can't seem to modify its current behavior of parsing the most recent commits since last running `grunt changelog`.

Thanks!

Comment: Check out https://github.com/rafinskipg/git-changelog

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the [git-changelog](https://github.com/rafinskipg/git-changelog) grunt plugin, it provides an option `tag` for specifying the git tag from which you want to generate the Changelog from (providing false for commits from the beginning)

```
git_changelog: {
    extended: {
        options: {
            repo_url: 'https://github.com/repo/repo-name',
            app_name: 'Repo Name',
            tag: false //False for commits since the beginning
        }
    }
}
```